# Under Linux, how do I copy files from one filesystem to the other (both gpfs) and preserve hard links?

Tags: linux, filesystems, copy, hardlink

I have a directory with huge files and a number of directories, that have hardlinks on these huge files. How do I copy files from one filesystem to the other and preserve hard links?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @quanta It's Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tar` is preserving links (both symbolic and hard ones).  To copy between filesystems, you would use it that way:

```
tar -cf - -C srcdir . | tar -xpf - -C destdir
```

See the `tar` man page for more details (this is where this example is actually coming from).

Answer (score 4):

`rsync` can preserve hard-links with the `-H` option.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cp -r --preserve=links src dst
```

[**`man cp`**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cp):

```
   --preserve[=ATTR_LIST]
          preserve  the specified attributes (default: mode,ownership,timestamps), 
          if possible additional attributes: context, links, xattr, all
```

Comment: From the man page, it is not very clear that `cp` invoked that way preserves both symbolics and hard links.  But after some testing, that seems to work, interesting!